# Visual Studios 2015 C++ UML diagramm creating associations

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, associations, uml

I wrote an c++ application using Visual Studios 2015 for a class project in my school. Therefor, I have to submit an UML-Classdiagramm. I already heard of VS's ability of auto-generating UML diagramms from my written classes.

So I right-clicked on my solution explorer and generated this UML. I removed some unnecessary classes and already displayed some Members as association.

Now I want to associate some classes with each other because VS didn't do this for me. Those are one-to-many-associations like one bag associates with many items in it. 
In code, I did this with a vector. but when I right-click the property and select "Show as Association" (or something similar :D) it keeps adding the vector-class instead of drawing my association to the class-type stored in this vector.

I also tried to add the associations manually but I can't because all the UML-classdiagramm-Items in my Toolbox are gray and not usable.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Visual Studio doesn't support this for C++. You have to create a new Diagram Project (not just adding it to your current project) and design your classes manually. The auto-generated class diagram works for C# (only?).

Comment: If it works for C#, it probably works for any other .NET language.

Comment: Yep, I wasn't sure about that either.